Is there a way to apply an entity tag to a method that it cannot be applied to?
public static boolean isHuman(Entity pEntity) {
        return pEntity.is(ModEntityTags.HUMANS);
    }

im trying to use a custom tag i made for this method however the 'is' method from the Entity class can only be applied on entities and not tags, the error says 'is(net.minecraft.world.entity.Entity)' in 'net.minecraft.world.entity.Entity' cannot be applied to '(net.minecraft.tags.TagKey<net.minecraft.world.entity.EntityType<?>>)'
i tried casting ModEntityTags.HUMANS to Entity hoping that could solve the problem but it didn't work

Why do you think the is method is appropriate for what you're trying to do?

since i want it to declare what type of tag the entity should have for the boolean to be true, its the closest method i found that does what i want to do, i've seen another class before with a similar 'is' method that allowed tags to be applied to it
